# Why does changes to the outer scope from within a directive require scope.$apply() even if I am setting scope option to false?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Lately I've noticed that changed to some angular - provider objects, or to my own - outer scope(out side of the directive, in the controllers) required wrapping the code in scope.apply().

can anyone please elaborate on this rather strange behavior behavior?.

Apply is a way for angular to recognize something that had happened outside of it's own scope(different library etc.), an angular directive definitely doesn't fall in that definition.

example code:

```
app.directive('socialAuth', function(utils, authService, $location){
    return{
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: false,
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
                elem.bind('click', function(){
                            utils.cleanSocialSearch();
                            if(attrs.checkbox){
                              scope.$apply(function(){
                                scope.model.personalShare[attrs.network] = true;  
                                $location.search('presonalShare', '1');//those 2 do nothing outside of the $apply function
                              });
                            }
                            var callback = encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
                            var loginUrl = utils.getBaseUrl() + '/social/login/' + attrs.network + '?success_url=' + callback;

                              location.href = loginUrl;  


                        });
            }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2):

`$apply` is needed when you need to tell `Angular` that something happened outside its context. That way `Angular` can refresh the bindings.

In short, what you bind using `elem.bind` are classic events, not angular stuff. So `elem.bind('click'...)` is binding the `click event` which is a classic event (Like `focus`, `blur`, etc). Classic events are processed outside angular context, so you need to $apply to make angular know.

You can read [here](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/watch-how-the-apply-runs-a-digest/) if you need more details :)

Answer (score 1):

In your example it's because the code is a click event handler which is handled by the browser.

**So what determines whether `apply()` is needed is the execution context within which the code will run.**  In this case even though Angular sets up the callback (handler), as you note, it's the browser that executes it because its an asynchronous event handler triggered by a browser event.  And thus the need to inform Angular.